# Javascript login with loading txt file

Tags: javascript

I want to make javascript login screen(im not best java programmer)
and i got this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function TheLogin() {

var password = 'password1';

if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
  top.location.href="correct.html";
}
else {
  window.alert("Incorrect password, please try again.");
  }
}

</script>
```

but, i dont want to have simple variable to be my password, i want to load password from txt file... Soo

I would be var password = something.txt

and in something.txt

password1

How its that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about the txt file, neither the first nor the second solution are save and both shouldn't be used. Authentication is done server-side

Comment: Yea, but the code shown its pretty bad..Because if you inspect element, you can see password :|

Comment: Which is why you don't do the authentication on the client side.

Comment: Authentication should **ALWAYS** be done server side.

Comment: But how can i make it secure?

Comment: @AleksejJovanovic You NEED to have the password somewhere on a server. You can do that through PHP. If the password entered matches the PHP variable, you can redirect to the correct page afterwards. You NEED to have it stored on a server. Even a .txt file can be read by anyone.

Comment: @AleksejJovanovic - you cannot.

Comment: Oh..:/ Dang it! Thanks guys for answering me..

Comment: Have a nice night/day!